# .NET 4.5 WebApi or WCF Services. When?

Tags: .net, wcf

I am not clear when you need to use the WebAPI or WCF services. What are the best practices?
They can you clarify the differences?

Answer (score 3):

You can see more information regarding WCF and WEB Api here

[WCF vs Web api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172.aspx)